# How to load a twig template based on rules

Tags: php, twig

I'd like to load different templates depending on whether a given file exists. E.g. by default I would load templates from a base folder, but if a specific folder exists then I would load that template instead. I'm picturing some functionality similar to an autoload function offers. Does twig offer this ability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends if you want to either

- load templates from directory A or directory B if it exists, but not both
- load directory B if it exists, and make it take precedence over directory A

Examples

```
// Load both directories
$loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem($baseTemplateDir);

if (is_dir($secondTemplateDir)) {
    $loader->prependPath($secondTemplateDir);
}


// Load one directory
$loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem(
    is_dir($secondTemplateDir) ? $secondTemplateDir : $baseTemplateDir
);
```

Alternatively

```
// Load both directories
try {
    $loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem(array(
        $secondTemplateDir,
        $baseTemplateDir
    ));
} catch (\Twig_Error_Loader $e) {
    $loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem($baseTemplateDir);
}

// Load one directory
try {
    $loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem($secondTemplateDir);
} catch (\Twig_Error_Loader $e) {
    $loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem($baseTemplateDir);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I realized after taking a step away from the keyboard that all my twig stuff goes through a proxy class so I am literally quite free to futz with the loading however I wish. This should be helpful though. Have a lovely day!